# How would I know if there is any similar element in my array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have this code which lists all files in my directory:

```
$dir = '/var/www/corpIDD/rawFile/';
opendir DIR, $dir or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!";
my @file= readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;
```

which returns an array containing something like this:

```
$array (0 => 'ipax3_2011_01_27.txt', 1 => 'ipax3_2011_02_01.txt', 2 => 'ipax3_2011_02_03.txt')
```

My problem here is, how will I store elements 1 => 'ipax3_2011_02_01.txt' and 2 => 'ipax3_2011_02_03.txt' to separate variable as they belong to the same month and year(2011_02)?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried:     # search for pattern "year_month" in array elements; 
$search = $year."_".$this_month;
@match = grep (/$search/i, @file); 
but this will only look for any files for the current month. I need something that will look for any files with two or more entries for the same month in my directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl, when you need to use a string as the key in a data structure, you are looking for the `HASH` builtin type, designated by the `%` sigil.  A nice feature of Perl's hashes is that you do not have to pre-declare a complex data structure.  You can use it, and Perl will infer the structure from that usage.

```
my @file = qw(ipax3_2011_01_27.txt ipax3_2011_02_01.txt ipax3_2011_02_03.txt);

my %ipax3;

for (@file) {
    if (/^ipax3_(\d{4}_\d{2})_(\d{2}).txt$/) {
        $ipax3{$1}{$2} = $_
    }
    else {
        warn "bad file: $_\n"
    }
}

for my $year_month (keys %ipax3) {
    my $days = keys %{ $ipax3{$year_month} };
    if ($days > 1) {
        print "$year_month has $days files\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$year_month has 1 file\n";
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
2011_01 has 1 file
2011_02 has 2 files
```

To get at the individual files:

```
my $year_month = '2011_02';
my $day        = '01';
my $file       = $ipax3{$year_month}{$day};
```

Above I used the return value of the `keys` function as both the list to iterate over, and as the number of days.  This is possible because `keys` will return all of the keys when in list context, and will return the number of keys in scalar context.  Context is provided by the surrounding code:

```
my $number = keys %ipax3; # number of year_month entries

my @keys = keys %ipax3; # contains ('2011_01', '2011_02') 

my @days = keys %{ $ipax{$year_month} };
```

In the last example, each value in `%ipax` is a reference to a hash.  Since `keys` takes a literal hash, you need to wrap `$ipax{$year_month}` in `%{ ... }`.  In perl v5.13.7+ you can omit the `%{ ... }` around arguments to `keys` and a few other data structure access functions.

Comment: wow! that is sooo great! Im a newbie to perl that's why I didn't know much of this functions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

People are responding really fast here :) anyway, I'll post mine, just for your reference. Basically, I'm also using a hash.

```
use warnings qw(all);
use strict;

my ($dir, $hdir) = 'C:\Work';
opendir($hdir, $dir) || die "Can't open dir \"$dir\" because $!\n";
my (@files) = readdir($hdir);
closedir($hdir);

my %yearmonths;
foreach(@files)
{
    my ($year, $month);
    next unless(($year, $month) = ($_ =~ /ipax3_(\d{4})_(\d{2})/));
    $year += 0;
    --$month;           #assuming that months are in range 1-12
    my $key = ($year * 12) + $month;
    ++$yearmonths{ $key };
}
foreach(keys %yearmonths)
{
    next if($yearmonths{ $_ } < 2);
    my $year = $_ / 12;
    my $month = 1 + ($_ % 12);
    printf "There were %d files from year %d, month %d\n", $yearmonths{$_}, $year, $month;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! those were great also!